# XPath to select nodes whose name starts with

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<detail>
  <address>
    <line1/>
    <line2/>
    <line3/>
    <postcode/>
  </address>
</detail/>
```

There could be any number of `<line*>` nodes which I want to select, and other nodes which I don't want to select.

I have tried this, which doesn't seem to work (in C# anyway):

```
/detail/address/[substring(name(),4) = 'line']
```

Al, help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
/detail/address/*[starts-with(name(), 'line')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using XDocuments.

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants())
        {

            if(element.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("line"))
               //DoStuffWithValueOfThatElement(element.Value)...
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `contains`:

```
/detail/address/*[contains(name(),'line')]
```

If you want to use `substring` you've to know that the index starts with 1 and you're also missing the wildcard:

```
/detail/address/*[substring(name(),1,4) = 'line']
```

Answer (score 1):

From memory, I think the index is 1 based not 0 based. Perhaps this will work:

```
/detail/address/[substring(name(),1,3) = 'line']
```

Alternatively, do you have control over the format of the XML? If so, a better approach might be to structure it like so:

```
<detail>
  <address>
    <line number='1'/>
    <line number='2'/>
    <line number='3'/>
    <postcode/>
  </address>
</detail/>
```

Then you can use the following to retrieve the lines:

```
/detail/address/line
```

Comment: Unfortunately no control over XML shape, but good thought thanks!